# Does the _id in content providers table needs to be in sequence

Tags: android

I am using content providers for my application.the app will register the added user to server.the server send id for that user.i need to populate the listview from the content providers data.can i use that id as _id for content providers table because the server's id may not be in a  sequence.

Is it work on the non sequence id's.or I need to go for other options

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about id that comes from your server side.
From API guide:

> A provider isn't required to have a primary key, and it isn't required to use _ID as the column name of a primary key if one is present. However, if you want to bind data from a provider to a ListView, one of the column names has to be _ID. This requirement is explained in more detail in the section [Displaying query results](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults).

Basically, if server id is unique you may use it